# How to add your own custom css to override react-confirm-alert defaults

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-selectors

I'm using this confirmation popup from `react-confirm-alert`:

```js
   popup = _id => {
    confirmAlert({
      title: "Delete user",
      message: "Are you sure?",
      buttons: [
        {
          label: "Ja",
          onClick: () => this.deleteUserHandler(_id)
        },
        {
          label: "Nej",
        }
      ],
      closeOnEscape: true,
      closeOnClickOutside: true,
    });
  }
```

Is there a way to style it? I can set the overlay like so.

```css
.react-confirm-alert-overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

But I have no idea how to change the buttons, message or label. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the rendered example:

```html
<div id="react-confirm-alert">
  <div class="react-confirm-alert-overlay">
    <div class="react-confirm-alert">
      <div class="react-confirm-alert-body">
        <h1>Confirm to submit</h1>
        Are you sure to do this.
        <div class="react-confirm-alert-button-group"><button>Yes</button><button>No</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can target the elements by their class name (`.react-confirm-alert`, `.react-confirm-alert-body`, `.react-confirm-alert-button-group`, etc.), or by using child selectors (`.react-confirm-alert-body h1`, `.react-confirm-alert-button-group button`, `.react-confirm-alert-button-group button:first-child`, etc.).

You can also create and pass down your own custom UI component which you can style any way you want:

```js
confirmAlert({
  customUI: ({ onClose }) => {
    return (
      <div className="alert">
        <h1 className="alert__title">Are you sure?</h1>
        <p className="alert__body">You want to delete this file?</p>
        <button onClick={onClose} className="alert__btn alert__btn--no">No</button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.handleClickDelete();
            onClose();
          }}
          className="alert__btn alert__btn--yes"
        >
          Yes, Delete it!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-confirm-alert#custom-ui-component

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, this is a good start, exactly what I was looking for. How do I center the whole alert box? I've tried padding, margin and so on but it doesn't move. I've even tried .react-confirm-alert{position:relative}

Comment: You're welcome. It should probably be a new question, but if you've tried `position: relative`, you can add `top: 50%;` to move the top to the middle and `transform: translateY(-50%);` to move it up again by half of the box. You'll maybe need to add `margin: auto` too. If the answer above helped to solve your issue, you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark button next to it ;)

Comment: I just checkmarked it :). I cannot thank you enough, much appreciated. Any idea how to target the message (the text in between asking 'Are you sure?') in my example?

Comment: Thanks :) Unfortunately they didn't add a `div` around the message so it's not so straightforward. You can change the style of `.react-confirm-alert-body` and update the style of the `h1` and buttons to change them back. Not ideal, but that's probably the easiest if you don't want to add a custom UI.

Comment: Much appreciated mate, thanks a lot and have a pleasant day or night.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

```
.react-confirm-alert-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

[image]